# 4 same garbage characters at the end of my string

Tags: c++

So whenever I run my program it prints out the string as I want it to but adds 4 of the same '²' characters at the end every time and I don't know where they're coming from. When I run it in release mode instead of debug it prints a bunch of random characters at the end.
https://gyazo.com/3e17f2fb3ff80d2bcefe6212f695d682

```
#pragma once // this is all in a header file and building it in debug mode x86
#include "stdafx.h"
/*  #ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL 0
#else */

#define CurrentTime (__int16)0 

std::string GenerateIdentifiers(const __int16 size)
{
    srand(time(CurrentTime));
    __int16 index{ 0 };
    std::array<char, sizeof("ABCDEF0123456789")> UUID = {"ABCDEF0123456789"};
    char *arrChar = new char[size];

    for(__int16 x = 0; x < size; ++x) 
    {
        index = rand() % ((sizeof(UUID) / sizeof(UUID[0]) - 1));
        arrChar[x] = UUID[index];
    }

    return std::string(arrChar);
}
```

I expect the output to just be the string without the trailing ²²²²'s

Comment: Aigh! This has got to be some of the scariest code I've seen for generating UUIDs. It has a major security flaw, and several bugs. Why are you doing this instead of using some function that's already been written for you? Do not, under any circumstances, actually use this code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has got to be some of the worst code I've ever seen for doing this. It contains a major security flaw as well as several bugs, including a memory leak. The funny characters you see at the end of your string due to your misunderstanding of how to use the `::std::string` API are the least of your worries. Just the most visible.

First, under no circumstances should you be using the `rand` function for this purpose. If you need a random number generator for a game or a Monte Carlo simulation, that's an OK (but still not very good) generator to use. For generating UUIDs it's downright dangerous. Luckily, the C++ standards committee thought of this and created something called `::std::random_device` that is a cross-platform standard way of getting a secure random number generator.

Here is an example of a bug-free version of the function that uses the appropriate API:

```
//#pragma once // this is all in a header file and building it in debug mode x86
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

/*  #ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL nullptr
#else */

std::string GenerateIdentifiers(const ::std::uint16_t size)
{
    using ::std::array;
    static constexpr array<char, 16> hex_translate{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    ::std::random_device rd;
    // Unfortunately uniform_int_distribution, unlike most other ranges, includes both ends.
    // So a fixup to size() is needed because it's one past the end (like most ranges in C++).
    ::std::uniform_int_distribution<::std::uint16_t> dist(0, hex_translate.size() - 1);

    ::std::string uuid;
    uuid.resize(size);

    for(::std::uint16_t x = 0; x < size; ++x) 
    {
        uuid[x] = hex_translate[dist(rd)];
    }

    return uuid;
}
```

The problems fixed... initializing an `::std::array` from a character string tends not to work very well. Mostly because character strings get an extra `'\0'` tacked onto the end (i.e. `sizeof("ABCDEF0123456789")` is 17, not 16). This could be fixed with some nice `constexpr` library functions, but absent this, the best thing is just use a list of characters instead and be explicit about the length.

Related to the size issue, your use of `sizeof(UUID) / sizeof(UUID[0]) - 1` is silly. First, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1. Second, `::std::array` has a perfectly serviceable `size` member function to use for just this purpose. And lastly, your application of the `- 1` fudge factor indicates that your program had a weird bug that you patched over by figuring out you could put `- 1` someplace instead of addressing the root cause (the trailing `'\0'` on your constant).

Also, this array was misnamed, which makes your code confusing. It isn't a UUID, it's a bunch of (out of order, but for this purpose it doesn't matter) hex digits used for creating a hex string. So, it's a hex translation constant. And it's constant. It should never change over the entire lifetime of your program, so it should be `constexpr` and `static`.

Also, you use `new` to allocate a character array `arrChar` but never free it, thereby causing a memory leak. You shouldn't ever be using raw pointers in C++ anymore, and this is a textbook illustration as to why. You should use one of the standard C++ data structures for holding a dynamically sized bunch of data. And there happens to be one that's already specialized for characters, which is `::std::string`.

Lastly, you are using `rand` to generate random numbers that will presumably be used for some kind of globally unique identifier (judging by your use of UUID as a variable name). This is a completely inappropriate use of this function. And the way you seed it makes it even worse. You are highly likely to generate colliding IDs this way (two runs of the program generating the same ID). Additionally these IDs will be trivially guessed by an outside third party, and frequently people using IDs like this expect them to be unique and unknown by anybody before they're used.

As of C++11 (which various features of your code indicate you're likely using), C++ has the ability to generate secure and really random numbers as a standard library feature. The appropriate thing to use is `::std::random_device` combined with `::std::uniform_int_distribution`.

As a bonus, using a `::std::string` for your dynamically allocated array of characters permits the compiler to apply the return value optimization.  It also eliminates the need to add the trailing `'\0'` the lack of which caused the problem your post was originally about. Unless you use this function in a tight loop somewhere, it's unlikely to be a huge deal performance-wise, but every little bit helps, and you should get in the habit of writing for this optimization anyway because it's also usually good programming practice to do so.

Comment: Thank you for saying it, it's giving me a headache too. Feel free to add these to your answer: A) `sizeof("ABCDEF0123456789")` is actually 17, not 16. B) `arrChar` is leaked. C) `(sizeof(UUID) / sizeof(UUID[0]) - 1)` is meaningless nonesense and should be replaced by `UUID.size()`. Obviously the use of `rand()` and `srand()` is harmful, especially with the bad joke that is `CurrentTime` which makes this function behave identically each time it is called.

Comment: @alterigel - Oh, I missed the problem of `sizeof("string")` being wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that, after C++11, a [uniform distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) should, in theory, work fine too.

Comment: @Chipster - No, uniform_distribution won't help. But `::std::random_device` will if the implementation has it. I forgot about that. _sheepish grin_. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 6):

`arrChar` is not NUL-terminated. `std::string` constructor expects a pointer to a NUL-terminated string. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.